# Proving that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \cos(x) = \cos(x_0)$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

So, here's what I'm trying to prove:

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $\lim_{x \to x_0} \cos(x) = \cos(x_0)$

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, we have to show that:

$$\exists \delta > 0: 0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)| < \epsilon$$

I'm going to start by simplifying that expression with the cosines:

$$\cos(x) = \cos[\frac{x+x_0}{2}+\frac{x-x_0}{2}]$$

$$\cos(x) = \cos(\frac{x+x_0}{2})\cos(\frac{x-x_0}{2}) - \sin(\frac{x+x_0}{2})\sin(\frac{x-x_0}{2})$$

$$\cos(x_0) = \cos[\frac{x_0+x}{2}+\frac{x_0-x}{2}]$$

$$\cos(x_0) = \cos(\frac{x_0+x}{2})\cos(\frac{x_0-x}{2}) - \sin(\frac{x_0+x}{2})\sin(\frac{x_0-x}{2})$$

$$\cos(x)-\cos(x_0) = 2\sin(\frac{x_0+x}{2})\sin(\frac{x_0-x}{2})$$

So, we have:

$$|\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)| = 2|\sin(\frac{x_0+x}{2})| \cdot |\sin(\frac{x_0-x}{2})| \leq 2 |\sin(\frac{x_0-x}{2}|$$

$$|\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)| \leq 2 \cdot |\frac{x_0-x}{2}| = |x-x_0| < \delta$$

So, let $\delta = \epsilon$ and that proves the given assertion.

Could someone check through the proof above and see if I'm correct or not? I'm sorry if anything seems out of place, I'll try to fix it if the errors are just too large to ignore.

Comment: Very convoluted way for writing $\cos x$ and $\cos x_0$. There is a formula for $\cos a-\cos b$. There is no need to derive it. Otherwise the solution is good.

Comment: Ah yea, I was trying my hardest to not refer to the formulae cos I don't usually have those off the top of my head. That's why I derived it in the way I did. Thank you for looking through my proof!

Comment: You have an algebraic error:
$$\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)=2\sin\left(\frac{x_0+x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x_0-x}{2}\right) $$
Everything else looks correct, though.

Comment: Oh wow I'm an idiot. Thanks

Comment: Your proof is fine.  You might be interested  on  [prosthapharesis formulae](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities)

Comment: That's pretty cool, actually